# Google Apps Script moving file to Team Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

**Background:**
At the core of the issue is I have an Alteryx job dropping files into my google drive. These files need, in actuality, in a Team Drive folder. Try as I might, nowhere have I found a way for Alteryx to do this. So hence the need for this script.

**Actual problem:**
So here is the criteria: I have the files being created with the same naming convention with only the date changing. I need these files to go from my drive to a team drive where they are eventually worked on.
Using the resources already here on stack I found wonderful solutions here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385933/google-apps-script-move-my-drive-files-to-team-drive-folder-based-on-file-name) and here [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302468/how-to-move-a-file-from-mydrive-to-team-drive) that I was able to cobble together a working script.

*Understand I am a marginally functional python programmer for data analytics.* So my JS and Google scripting are rudimentary at best. The first time I tested the script, it worked. Wonderfully, right up until it didn't. 
It moved my first file with no problem. I then created a few copies of that same file in the drive to see how it handled multiple. I now get an error:

> Exception: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not
>   have permission to access it. (line 15, file "CodeA1")

Here is my code:

```
function SearchFiles() {
  //searches based on naming criteria 
  var searchFor ='title contains "Reference Data Performance"'; //test file
  var names =[];
  var fileIds=[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
    fileIds.push(fileId);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name); 

  }
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds);
supportsTeamDrives: true;
        supportTeamDrives: true;
        var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('TEAMDriveID');
        targetFolder.addFile(file);

}
```

Comment: `.getFileById()` doesn't seem to support arrays, maybe try looping through them instead.

Comment: That may be but even, with just a single file in the drive, I get the same error. So it worked once, and now I cant get it to run again....

Comment: I don't understand this line `var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIds);`  It's a `getFileById()` but you give an array of Ids. Also something is missing in the bottom part of the function where you building an object.  I'm guessing you made a mistake copying you code into SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not
>   have permission to access it.

This error occurs most often if either

- The `TeamDriveId` is not correct
- The account from which you run the script is not member of the team drive

> Also note:
>
> `supportsTeamDrives: true;
>   supportTeamDrives: true;`
>
> are parameters
>   for the `Drive API`, not to be confused with `DriveApp`

Comment: Very true! I got an email from our cyber security. Essentially I have access to all drives but even though I put in all the requisite filings for the app to have access. I am awaiting access rights again. Worked the first time, though I know it can be much smoother than I am presenting it as.

Comment: I am glad you found the reason. If the answer for you, consider accepting it to increase visibility for other users having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I ended up going with a simplified version of this script. I had Alteryx schedule the file creation (three different files) at hour increments. Then made a trigger in Google Apps to run the script at the times directly after each Alteryx scheduled drop. Simple? Yes. Inelegant? Maybe. Been running all week and files arrive at their destination for people to work on.

```
function SearchFiles() {
  //searches based on naming criteria 
  var searchFor ='title contains "Reference Data Performance"'; //looks for file that matches requirements
   var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file


      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId); //grabs file ready to pass to google drive.
supportsTeamDrives: true;
        supportTeamDrives: true;
        var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID');
        targetFolder.addFile(file);//good for getting a single file needs loop to grab multiple from Array

  }

}
```